# C# Subcommands within console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I would like to have commands within the executable itself for example:

```
shorten http://stackoverflow.com/
```

and the url will be parsed as an argument, if I set it to return the argument, it should return me `http://stackoverflow.com/`

Another example is

```
foo bar
```

and it will check what is the main command which is `foo` and subcommands under it, which is `bar` and will execute the command.

This should be done within the executable and not calling the executable in the directory. I would like to have multiple custom commands within the executable and not create one for each command.

I understand how to have arguments if each command was an executable, but I would like a few commands and subcommands within 1 executable. Is this possible?

**EDIT**:

This is what I want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i] == "short")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

which will return me the arguments of `short`. So if I type `short link` it will return me `link`.

However this will only work if I call the executable through the command line like `C:\Path\ConsoleApplication1.exe` not if I open up the application and type `short link`, which will not return me anything and close.

How do I make it work when I open up the application and type it in?

Comment: Sure it's possible... But question in current state is too broad and a bit unclear

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: Try to use `Console.ReadLine`

Comment: @w.b Yes, but i'm not sure how to separate the main command from the arguments/parameters, if I use `Console.ReadLine`, I don't know how to get the arguments so that I can parse it into a method. If it's a fixed command I can use `if(input.Equals("command subcommand"))`, but now I want to get the subcommand as an argument/parameter, not just checking if the command and arguments match together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Console.ReadLine`:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```

To get command and argument(s) use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var command = input.Split()[0];
var argument1 = input.Split()[1];
```

etc.

Comment: How do I check if the string/input has an argument and not only a command?

Comment: @pleasega - check the length of the array you will get with `input.Split()`, if it's == 1 then you have just a command,  if it's > 1 then there are arguments as well